# Find iD1, iD3 and Vo for Vi=3V & Vi=-3V. (Diodes)

Tags: diodes

I was just wondering if my solution to the attached question is correct or not?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you are correct.

You should also learn how to use a simulator. The one built in here is good enough to check your work in simple problems like this. Note I used simple switches for the diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMD3Nh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvUZRW.png)</sup>

Don't cheat though. It's only for verification.